# Changes to parse-dateTime function behaviour

Tags: marklogic

I'm executing this function
xdmp:parse-dateTime("yyyy","2013")
in three different version of Marklogic.

In Marklogic 5 and 8 it works fine.
In Marklogic 7.0.5 I get an error:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-PATTERNVALUEMISMATCH: xdmp:parse-dateTime("yyyy",
>   "2013") -- Given value doesn't match with the specified pattern for
>   parsing dateTime string.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a  bug. There were some other fixes to xdmp:parse-dateTime and they seem to have broken this.

It was a bit of a bug that it worked in the first place, honestly. The right way to write this is: xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Y0001]",2002)

These are XSLT date/time patterns. The y is being interpreted as a literal.